# How to sync "session manager" sessions accross devices in Firefox?

Tags: session, firefox, synchronization, firefox-addon, firefox-sync

I've several devices that are kept in sync with the [native Firefox sync](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/sync/) but I don't see any options to sync my current state/session (opened tabs/windows) between them.

I use [session manager addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/session-manager/) to save and restore my session automatically but can't see any option to sync states/sessions across devices.

Do you know a solution?

Comment: A superb question! I would love to see the answer to this myself! I have been wanting to implement sync to my addons and show others an easy way to add it into theirs.

Comment: As written, this appears to be more a question about **general computing hardware and software** than it is about programming.  If it is about programming, perhaps you could make the question a bit more focused. As it is, it appears to be off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is easily possible through cloud-computing!

For example: I use google drive on my machines. 
I've set up Session Manager's session-store-folder on an google drive folder,
and did the same on all of my machines. Once I close the browser, the stored sessions are emediately synced on every machine. Opening Firefox on another Machine has the new stored files available and is able to restore any session on any of my machines.

I hope this helped you out!

Greetings 
Mike

Comment: I like the idea of storing sessions manager on a syncing app, however not the choice of Google drive. I would recommend a FLOSS solution such as [syncthing](http://syncthing.net/)

Comment: yeah thats a good point! I gave [Seafile](http://www.seafile.com) a try, which works very well for an a "own"-open-source-cloud solution, but you can only suggest this to users, they are able to install and configure server-aplications.